# Showing $| \phi^{-1}(g)| = |H \cap K|$ for any $g \in HK$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

> **Question**
> Let $G$ be a finite group and $H, K$ be subgroups of $G$. Define $HK := \{hk: h \in H, k \in K \}$.
>
> Let $\phi: H \times K \rightarrow HK$ be defined by $(h,k) \mapsto hk$. Then $|\phi^{-1}(g)| = |H \cap K|$ for any $g \in HK$.

I think this question is asking me to find a suitable bijective $\varphi:\phi^{-1}(g) \rightarrow H \cap K$ which implies that the two sets are equinumerous. I am struggling to find a definition for $\varphi$ which is bijective since I can't see why $\phi^{-1}(g)$ necessarily contains elements of $H \cap K$.

Am I heading down the right path with this? If not, what else can I think about trying that may lead to a cardinality argument for the two sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $g\in HK$ let $g=h'k'$ with $h'\in H$ and $k'\in K$. Let $(h,k)\in\phi^{-1}(g)$. Then $hk=g=h'k'$, therefore $h'^{-1}h=k'k^{-1}\in H\cap K$. Let $\varphi$ be defined as:

$$\varphi: \phi^{-1}(g)\to H\cap K,\ (h,k)\mapsto h'^{-1}h=k'k^{-1}$$

Its inverse map is given by:

$$\psi: H\cap K\to\phi^{-1}(g),\ x\mapsto (h'x,x^{-1}k')$$

Answer (score 1):

You could proceed as follows: 
take any $g \in HK$ and write $g = hk$ with $h \in H$ and $k \in K$. Then $\phi^{-1}(g)$ consists of all pairs $(h',k')$ with $h'k'=hk$. If you take $h' = hx$ and $k' = x^{-1}k$ for $x \in H\cap K$ you already get $|H\cap K|$ distinct elements of $\phi^{-1}(g)$. It remains to show that all elements of $\phi^{-1}(g)$ are of this form